# IdentityServer V3 does not accept login

Tags: thinktecture-ident-server, identityserver3

We are trying to build OAuth2 Authorization with IdentityServer3.

So we downloaded the Bytes from nuget and connected it with our database.
The database was initialized with the default scopes and the sample clients from Thinktecture self.
Then we connected AD FS as IDP via OWIN and made an simple ExternalUserService.

So far everything worked fine and the permissions page of the IdSrv could be opened, showing the username and that no application has consent up to now.

Then we tried to connect Xamarin.Auth to that and got an error *Cannot determine application to sign in to* and in the logs an error Signin Id not present (after logon at the ADFS IDP).

To reduce complexity, we decided to go back to the InMemoryUserService and created one InMemoryUser. This worked for the permissions page (at least for a short period of time - time is over now), but it did not allow OAuth2 Authorization Code Flow, which ended up in showing the login page again and again and again. And there is no evidence of any error in the logs.

How can we debug, what is happening? Is there any way to see, why a user gets redirected to the login page again despite being logged in?

--

We reduced the complexity even further by creating a new empty MVC application, which just uses a simple InMemoryUserFactory.
Now it's getting a little bit confusing: one user was able to logon from his machine - other machines (same user - since we created only one) are not able to login and get prompted with the login over and over again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using IdentityServer3 and you use own external login methods you should really pay close attention to the API of the IdSrv3.

We tried to create a login resutl with just the subject - this is made for local login on the server. If this is switched off at the same time, you will end up having problems.

So if you use an own external login provider and switch off local login, make sure to call the right overload for the authenticate method (3 Parameters in our case).